# Is there a way to see all outgoing emails in Postal Mail Server?

Tags: email, email-server

I am using [Postal](https://github.com/postalhq/postal) and all is going well but suddenly Google is soft failing me for sending too many messages, but I haven't sent very many!

I want to check if someone unauthorized is using the server as a relay, but I couldn't find any `mail.log` in `/var/log` and the postal log is empty.

How can I find all emails being sent from this server? The OS is Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Thanks!

Comment: Normal behavior of your mail server is to log the mail transactions. If it doesn’t ; check your config. If your server is still not logging anything: there may be mail traffic that is sent without using your internal mail server. That can either be a valid application or that can be the result of a compromise.

Comment: @HermanB - is that normal behavior of mail servers, or specifically for the Postal mail server? I set it up following the normal instructions and can't find documentation for logs config.